# how to update id as row number in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql

My talbe `article_favorites` did not have row number, right now it contains 100000 record. I want to add a bigint id column in the talbe and set the id as row number by default. I tried this sql:

```
update article_favorites  set id = row_number() OVER ()
```

but it tell me the `window functions are not allowed in UPDATE`, what should I do to update the id as row number?

Answer (score 5):

Using a sequence might be faster than using `row_number()`

```
create sequence id_seq;
update article_favorites  
  set id = nextval('id_seq');
drop sequence id_seq;
```

Comment: I guess we should use a temp sequence here: `CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE ..` which will be dropped automatically, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

As the error you're encountering mentions, window functions can't be used in an `UPDATE` statement BUT you can define them ahead of time in a CTE or subquery, and use their evaluated results in the `UPDATE` statement. IF you have a unique way to identify the row already, then you can accomplish your goal like so:

```
WITH _article_favorites_rowids AS
(
    SELECT uniqueField, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS newId
    FROM _article_favorites
)

UPDATE a
SET a.id = r.newId
FROM _article_favorites a
INNER JOIN _article_favorites_rowids r
    ON a.uniqueField = r.uniqueField
```

Comment: `uniqueField` is usually the id, so it is hard to use another `uniqueField`, and I don't think we can use window functions in where clauses or join conditions. Any ideas if we don't have a usable `uniqueField` to link the data for the update?

Comment: @Rafs I don't follow. Does your data have a `uniqueField`?

Comment: No, no other unique fields apart from id

Answer (score 0):

You can add generated values when you create `id` column. The statement below creates a **auto generated** column and fills if for existing records.

```
ALTER TABLE article_favorites ADD id bigserial;
```

You can create primary key if your table does not have one or you can
just add unique key to that field.

```
ALTER TABLE article_favorites ADD id bigserial PRIMARY KEY; -- or UNIQUE
```

You can use `smallserial` or `serial` (represent integer data type) instead of `bigserial` (bigint data type). These types are not true types. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is document link related.